# How to change only width of path(rect, circle) while mouse drag using paper.js

Tags: html5-canvas, paperjs

I have stucked at resizing only width of  an item in the canvas using paper.js
I have done in following ways to resize , but it results in resizing both left and right sides from the center of rectangle/circle.

```
function onMouseDrag(event){

(selectedItem.bounds.contains(event.point)) ?
selectedItem.scale(0.9871668311944719,1) : selectedItem.scale(1.013, 1);
}
```

above code resizes in both x-directions.

Help me to resize width only in one direction.

thanks,

suribabu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center the scale operation at any point by using the form:

```
scale(hor, ver, point)
```

So in your case, if you want to scale from the left-center of your selected item, you could use:

```
function onMouseDrag(event){

(selectedItem.bounds.contains(event.point)) ?
selectedItem.scale(0.9871668311944719, 1, selectedItem.bounds.left) : selectedItem.scale(1.013, 1, selectedItem.bounds.left);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean with scale only the width. If you want to have thicker path than changing the `strokeWidth` instead might do what you want.

If you are wondering why the scaled path expands in both directions on the x-axis than you might check the location of the paths local center. If some nodes of the path have negative coordinates relative to this local center, scaling them with a positive value decreases their coordinates even more.

Perhaps you should normalize all the vertices, means move them directly so that the smallest x and y value of all vertices is 0.

Greetings and good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onMouseDown(e) {
    var cx = e.point.x;
    var cy = e.point.y;
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(e.point, new Size(1,1));
    path = new Path.Ellipse(rectangle);
    path.strokeColor = 'red';       
}

function onMouseDrag(e) {
    path.remove();
    var x = Math.min(e.point.x, cx),
        y = Math.min(e.point.y, cy),
        w = Math.abs(e.point.x -cx),
        h = Math.abs(e.point.y -cy);
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);
    path = new Path.Ellipse(rectangle);
    path.strokeColor = 'red'
}
```